# C# | new Bitmap(path)

Tags: c#, bitmap

Вопрос максимально плоский.

Есть получение изображений:

```
string[] imgs;
int look_index = 0;
while ((imgs = Directory.GetFiles(folder_path)).Length > look_index)
{
  // ...

  int w = 0, h = 0;
  try
  {
    using (Image img = new Bitmap(imgs[look_index]))
    {
      w = img.Width;
      h = img.Height;
    }
  }
  catch { }

  // ...
  // тут File.Move(imgs[look_index], folder_path + THIN + img_name);
  // ...
}
```

Путь в imgs[0] соответствует:

> "D:\_A_Private\Interested\Изображения\телефон\favorites\-TdhtbhWpKk.jpg"

Изображения по данному пути наличествуют.

В части итераций в отмеченном месте (при создании изображения) ловится затык:

> Вызвано исключение: "System.ArgumentException" в System.Drawing.dll

Изображения с разными именами и разных размеров,
но никакой зависимости в выпадающих исключениях не вижу.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Неправильное значение в аргументах вызова. Проще найти вопрос "как открыть jpg c#" и оттуда взять рабочий код. Через Bitmap похоже не будет работать.

Comment: @nick_n_a , нет, проблема явно не в этом.
Я скрыл исключения в try {} catch {} и запустил на своём массиве изображений.
Из около 3000 были обработаны нормально ~2650.
Но часть таки попала под "ArgumentException".
И я не пойму почему.
Имена везде по разному прописаны. Размеры разные.
Часть обработалась, часть нет.

(кстати, модифицированный код вставлю в основное описание в течение пары минут)

Comment: Bitmap поддерживает JPEG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @rotabor , именно так.
есть мысли на счёт исключения?

Comment: Может буквы православные в пути не понравились? Кодировка правильная?

Comment: Там, в часности, написано: "Due to a limitation of the GDI+ decoder, an System.ArgumentException is thrown if you construct a bitmap from a .png image file with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels". Нужно проверить, а что в файле, какой там в действительности формат изображения. Могут быть и другие ограничения, которые не описаны.

Comment: Я рекомендую составить список файлов, которые дают исключения (в catch писать имена в файл), а потом исследовать их.

Comment: @Qwer , в пути кириллица имеется, но в названиях изображений - нет. только комбинации цифро-букв + всякие там допустимые для файлов, типа "-" и "_". К тому же, как я и сказал, более 2 тыс. изображений обработку прошло. Но не все - а это уже печально.

Comment: @rotabor , .png'шек среди изображений как раз нет (или почти нет, а среди поймавших исключения - совсем нет). да и размеры изображений вполне адекватные, до 2000 по ширине \ высоте, так что проблем с размерностями быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Что же.
Как и сказал @rotabor , я немного поисследовал файлы с исключениями.
Это всё .jpg-файлы, и их отличие от обработанных - глубина цвета в 32b.

Немного поискав я встретил следующую информацию:

> JPEG - трехцветный формат. Обычно он имеет 8 бит на цвет, но может иметь 12 или 16.
> Следовательно, 24 = 3x8 бит цвета приемлемо, но 16 или 32 просто невозможно.
> Это просто не делится на три. 3x16 = 48 возможно, но это более высокая глубина цвета.
> JPEG предназначен для фотографий, и нет смысла поддерживать меньшую битовую глубину, чем 3x8.
> В этом нет никакой пользы.

Следовательно, изображения не обрабатываются потому, что они кривые изначально.
Вероятно, кто-то где-то сменил им расширение, не заботясь о внутренностях.

Так что вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: Есть повод зарепортить, всё-таки системная библиотека и должна полностью формат jpeg поддерживать.

Comment: Видел 12 и 16 в https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/512004/ SOF (Start of Frame) заголовке. 32 думаю не имеет смысла. Всё зависит то того кто или что есть источник таких JPEG, может какой то иобильный телефон такие делает. Ради интереса... хотелось бы увидеть дамп первых 256-1024 байт, где видно вверху производителя jpeg и SOF заголовок.